# Table with a sticky header overlapping problem

Tags: html, css

when having a table, I'm running into an issue with overlapping cells. I'd like the cells not to have any background color. When I sticky the first column so that it stays in place, when I scroll over it, the other values overlap with its text. 
I can fix that, by giving the header any background color (e.g. white). The issue with that is that I'd want to have a onhover effect for the whole row, which doesn't work if the th is given a background color of its own already.

### HTML

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow: auto;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="header">Hello</th>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
            <td>Value<td/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.header {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

/* th {
  background-color: white;
} */
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/Bishonen88/pen/rNaBRZp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
tr:hover > td {
  background-color: red;
}
```